# how to create a GUI using data from xml file?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, jaxb

what i want is to create a dynamic GUI that consists of a set of buttons ( in my case each button represents an element from the xml file ) and when i click a button  there will be a creation of buttons which represents its childs..i dnt know if it is possible to do that using DOM or JAXB..i'll be so thankful if anyone can help me or has another idea to do that!
thanks!!

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 

- <HWData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hw_data.xsd">

  <Header time="2015-02-03T02:02:56" uploaded="false" version="1.0" /> 

- <NE MOID="NE-SGSN-387826" objectClass="NE" objectClassVersion="1" NEId="387826" NEType="SGSN" systemTitle="SGSN-MNB-" locationName="MANOUBA" systemReleaseVersion="J8" softwareReleaseVersion="J8 50.70-0 50" serialNumber="387826" vendorName="Nokia">

- <EQHO MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" equipmentHolderId="11" equipmentHolderType="Cabinet" equipmentHolderSpecificType="EC217_A" locationName="1A" serialNumber="" interchangeability="" version="" identificationCode="" vendorName="Nokia">

- <EQHO MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-1-0" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" equipmentHolderId="11100" equipmentHolderType="Cartridge" equipmentHolderSpecificType="ACH16_A" locationName="1A001-00" serialNumber="XY131403380" interchangeability="" version="" identificationCode="" vendorName="Nokia">

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-1-0/UNIT-1-PIU-1" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="1" unitTypeActual="ACPI4_A" unitTypeExpected="ACPI4_A" position="1" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="FK124600007" interchangeability="B" version="3C" identificationCode="C111969" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-1-0/UNIT-1-RTM-1" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="1" unitTypeActual="CPRT4_A" unitTypeExpected="CPRT4_A" position="1" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="JG130400410" interchangeability="A" version="2A" identificationCode="C111970" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-1-0/UNIT-FAN-2" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400960" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-1-0/UNIT-FAN-1" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400980" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  </EQHO>

  <EQHO MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-1-0" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" equipmentHolderId="111000501" equipmentHolderType="Cartridge" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CHAF2_A" locationName="1A001-00-FFI-1" serialNumber="31401904" interchangeability="A" version="" identificationCode="C110639" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

- <EQHO MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-2-0" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" equipmentHolderId="11200" equipmentHolderType="Cartridge" equipmentHolderSpecificType="ACH16_A" locationName="1A002-00" serialNumber="XY131403370" interchangeability="" version="" identificationCode="" vendorName="Nokia">

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-2-0/UNIT-1-PIU-1" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="1" unitTypeActual="ACPI4_A" unitTypeExpected="ACPI4_A" position="1" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="FK124600059" interchangeability="B" version="3C" identificationCode="C111969" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-2-0/UNIT-SHM-2" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="3" unitTypeActual="ASMGR_A" unitTypeExpected="ASMGR_A" position="3" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131402619" interchangeability="A" version="4B" identificationCode="C110581" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-2-0/UNIT-FAN-3" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400977" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-2-0/UNIT-FAN-1" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400971" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-2-0/UNIT-FAN-2" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400975" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  </EQHO>

  <EQHO MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-2-0" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" equipmentHolderId="112000502" equipmentHolderType="Cartridge" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CHAF2_A" locationName="1A002-00-FFI-2" serialNumber="31401893" interchangeability="A" version="" identificationCode="C110639" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

- <EQHO MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-3-0" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" equipmentHolderId="11300" equipmentHolderType="Cartridge" equipmentHolderSpecificType="ACH16_A" locationName="1A003-00" serialNumber="XY131403377" interchangeability="" version="" identificationCode="" vendorName="Nokia">

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-3-0/UNIT-SHM-1" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="3" unitTypeActual="ASMGR_A" unitTypeExpected="ASMGR_A" position="3" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131301773" interchangeability="A" version="4B" identificationCode="C110581" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-3-0/UNIT-FAN-1" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400963" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-3-0/UNIT-FAN-2" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400962" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  <UNIT MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-3-0/UNIT-FAN-3" objectClass="UNIT" objectClassVersion="1" unitId="4" unitTypeActual="AFAMO_A" unitTypeExpected="AFAMO_A" position="4" operationalState="enabled" serialNumber="XY131400988" interchangeability="B" version="3B" identificationCode="C110638" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  </EQHO>

  <EQHO MOID="NE-SGSN-387826/DN:EQHO-1A/EQHO-3-0" objectClass="EQHO" objectClassVersion="1" equipmentHolderId="113000503" equipmentHolderType="Cartridge" equipmentHolderSpecificType="CHAF2_A" locationName="1A003-00-FFI-3" serialNumber="31401903" interchangeability="A" version="" identificationCode="C110639" vendorName="Nokia" /> 

  </EQHO>

  </NE>

  </HWData>
```

Comment: i gave an exmaple of the xml files that i deal with..if you take a look at the value of the MOID attribue you gonna notice that all the child elements have the same attribute value of their parent element concatinated with their values ( i am talking about the value of MOID attribute )

Comment: also i am dealing with xml files that i don't know their contents ( i mean the number of EQHO or UNIT ...)

Comment: What should happen besides child buttons appearing when their parent button is clicked?

Comment: same thing as their parent..when i click a child button its own children will appear if it has children !

Comment: Internet Explorer or any other XML viewing tool give you the same behavior. Do you just want to be able to view an XML file?

Comment: no Adriaan i have to represent it as i told u thats the goal of my project :\

Comment: Can you give us the XSD? (hw_data.xsd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed previous answer based on XStream in favor of JAXB.

Add the jaxb2-maven-plugin to your pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd/</schemaDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Put your XSD in src/main/resources/xsd/

The class HwDataTree extends [DynamicTreeDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/DynamicTreeDemoProject/src/components/DynamicTreeDemo.java) which is part of an Oracle tutorial. Download both classes and add them to your project.

```
import generated.EQHO;
import generated.HWData;
import generated.NE;
import generated.UNIT;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class HwDataTree extends DynamicTreeDemo {

    // the path of your XML file
    private static final String PATH = "C:/example.xml";

    @Override
    public void populateTree(DynamicTree treePanel) {
        HWData hwData = initData();
        treePanel.addObject(null, formatHeader(hwData));
        treePanel.addObject(null, formatNE(hwData));
        addNodesRecursive(hwData.getNE(), null, treePanel);
    }

    private HWData initData() {
        try {
            File xml = new File(PATH);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(HWData.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            return (HWData) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void addNodesRecursive(NE parent, DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode, DynamicTree treePanel) {
        List<EQHO> children = parent.getEQHO();
        for (EQHO child : children) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = treePanel.addObject(parentNode, formatEQHO(child));
            addNodesRecursive(child, childNode, treePanel);
        }
    }

    private void addNodesRecursive(EQHO parent, DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode, DynamicTree treePanel) {
        List<Object> children = parent.getEQHOAndUNIT();
        for (Object child : children) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = treePanel.addObject(parentNode, getMOID(child));
            if (child instanceof EQHO) {
                EQHO eqho = (EQHO) child;
                addNodesRecursive(eqho, childNode, treePanel);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getMOID(Object child) {
        String moid;
        if (child instanceof EQHO) {
            EQHO eqho = (EQHO) child;
            moid = formatEQHO(eqho);
        } else if (child instanceof UNIT) {
            UNIT unit = (UNIT) child;
            moid = formatUnit(unit);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse type of: " + child);
        }
        return moid;
    }

    private String formatHeader(HWData hwData) {
        return String.format("Header time=%s", hwData.getHeader().getTime());
    }

    private String formatNE(HWData hwData) {
        return String.format("NE MOID=%s", hwData.getNE().getMOID());
    }

    private String formatEQHO(EQHO child) {
        return String.format("EQHO MOID=%s", child.getMOID());
    }

    private String formatUnit(UNIT unit) {
        return String.format("UNIT MOID=%s", unit.getMOID());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tree");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        HwDataTree newContentPane = new HwDataTree();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Generate the wrappers by executing `mvn clean compile`.

Then run HwDataTree, the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: hey Adriaan the structure of my xml files look like this

HWData 
 Header
  NE
    EQHO*
      EQHO* 
          UNIT*

the children EQHOs can also have their own children so u dont really know the number how the structure gonna be

Comment: i have an xsd schema and it works fine but as i told you i dont know how to write my code in order to create buttons(or some like that) dynamically..

Comment: first i want to show one button that has the of NE and when i click their children appear(i mean a set of buttons having the name of EQHO or UNIT) 
and now when i click one of the children button its own children appear ... i hope you anderstand me!

Comment: Thank you so much Adriaan Koster :) gonna try it.. hope this will help me

Answer (score 1):

this is my xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSPY v5 rel. 4 U (http://www.xmlspy.com) by XMLSPY 5     Professional Ed. Release 4, Installed Multi + SMP for 2 users (Nokia GmbH) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.20">
<!--    Version history:
1.20: - changed "xsd" namespace according to W3C official recommendation
      - removed Telcordia specific pattern from EquipmentHolderSpecificTypes
      - added AvailabilityStatusEntry value "inCharge"
      - made "time" attribute in <Header/> mandatory
      - added serviceState attribute to PRUT
      - made PRUT attributes optional
      - added mnemonic attribute to EQHO
      - allow empty strings for attributes "position", "manufacturingDate", "dateOfLastService"
      - SoftwareReleaseVersionType: 20 -> 30

1.12: vendorName: mandatory, non-empty
1.11: PositionType: string -> integer 
      EquipmentHolderSpecificTypes: pattern refined according to Telcordia Network Engineer Java extensions
      Additional attributes in <Header/>
      time: timeInstant -> dateTime

1.10: Length of FunctionalUnitTypes: 4 -> 10
      Length of SoftwareReleaseVersionType: 10->20
      Length of VersionType: 5->30
-->
<xsd:simpleType name="AdministrativeState">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="locked"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="unlocked"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="shuttingDown"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="ConnectorTypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="DateOrEmptyType">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:date EmptyStringType"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<!-- whitespaces are allowed -->
<xsd:simpleType name="EmptyStringType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="\s*"/>
    </xsd:restriction> 
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="EquipmentHolderTypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Cabinet"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Rack"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Subrack"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Cartridge"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Slot"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="EquipmentHolderSpecificTypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="FunctionalUnitIdType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="FunctionalUnitTypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="HWCheckSumType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="IdentificationCodeType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="InterchangeabilityType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="LocationNameType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="MOID">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="256"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="MnemonicType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="NEAddressType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="256"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="[-_.0-9a-zA-Z]+=.*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="NamingAttributeIdType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="NameFromPlanningSystemType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="NETypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="NumberOfSlotsOccupiedType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="ObjectClassType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="5"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="ObjectClassVersionType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="100"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="OperationalState">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="disabled"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="enabled"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="PositionType">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:integer EmptyStringType"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="PowerSupplyTypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="ProtectionGroupTypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="plus"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="colon"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="SerialNumberType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="35"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="ServiceStateType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="active"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="standby"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="undefined"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="SoftwareReleaseVersionType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="SystemReleaseVersionType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="256"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="SystemTitleType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="256"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="UnitTypes">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="UserLabelType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="128"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="VendorNameType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="VersionType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="AvailabilityStatus">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="AvailabilityStatusEntry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="inCharge"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="inTest"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="failed"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="powerOff"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="offLine"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="offDuty"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="dependency"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="degraded"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="notInstalled"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="logFull"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="GlobalConnectorId">
    <xsd:attribute name="connectorHolderMOID" type="MOID"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="connectorIdentifier" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MOIDList">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="MOID" type="MOID" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="PhysicalConnectorList">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Connector" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:element name="connectedToIdentifier" type="GlobalConnectorId"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="connectorType" type="ConnectorTypes"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="connectorIdentifier" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="location" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:attributeGroup name="MOGeneralAttributes">
    <xsd:attribute name="MOID" type="MOID" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="objectClass" type="ObjectClassType"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="objectClassVersion" type="ObjectClassVersionType"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>
<xsd:attributeGroup name="MOStateAttributes">
    <xsd:attribute name="administrativeState" type="AdministrativeState"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="operationalState" type="OperationalState"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>
<xsd:element name="availabilityStatus" type="AvailabilityStatus"/>
<xsd:element name="physicalConnectorList" type="PhysicalConnectorList"/>
<xsd:element name="UNIT">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
            <xsd:element ref="availabilityStatus" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="physicalConnectorList" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOGeneralAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOStateAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="unitId" type="NamingAttributeIdType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="unitTypeActual" type="UnitTypes" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="unitTypeExpected" type="UnitTypes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="position" type="PositionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="numberOfSlotsOccupied" type="NumberOfSlotsOccupiedType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="userLabel" type="UserLabelType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="softwareReleaseVersion" type="SoftwareReleaseVersionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="vendorName" type="VendorNameType" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="version" type="VersionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="serialNumber" type="SerialNumberType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="manufacturingDate" type="DateOrEmptyType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="dateOfLastService" type="DateOrEmptyType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="interchangeability" type="InterchangeabilityType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="identificationCode" type="IdentificationCodeType"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="PRUT">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOGeneralAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="unitPointer" type="MOID"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="protectionUnitId" type="NamingAttributeIdType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="protecting" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="priority" type="xsd:integer"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="serviceState" type="ServiceStateType"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="EQHO">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="physicalConnectorList" type="PhysicalConnectorList" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element ref="EQHO" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element ref="UNIT" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOGeneralAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOStateAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="equipmentHolderId" type="NamingAttributeIdType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="equipmentHolderSpecificType" type="EquipmentHolderSpecificTypes" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="equipmentHolderType" type="EquipmentHolderTypes" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="userLabel" type="UserLabelType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="vendorName" type="VendorNameType" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="version" type="VersionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="position" type="PositionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="locationName" type="LocationNameType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="serialNumber" type="SerialNumberType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="manufacturingDate" type="DateOrEmptyType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="dateOfLastService" type="DateOrEmptyType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="interchangeability" type="InterchangeabilityType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="identificationCode" type="IdentificationCodeType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="mnemonic" type="MnemonicType"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="POSU">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="poweredEquipmentPtrList" type="MOIDList" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOGeneralAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="powerSupplyId" type="NamingAttributeIdType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="powerSupplyType" type="PowerSupplyTypes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="powerSource" type="xsd:integer"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="operationalState" type="OperationalState"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="FUUT">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
                <xsd:element name="supportedByUnitList" type="MOIDList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="affectedObjectList" type="MOIDList" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="FUUT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOGeneralAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOStateAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="functionalUnitId" type="FunctionalUnitIdType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="functionalUnitType" type="FunctionalUnitTypes" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="userLabel" type="UserLabelType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="version" type="VersionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="protected" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="PRGR">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="availabilityStatus" type="AvailabilityStatus" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="PRUT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOGeneralAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="protectionGroupId" type="NamingAttributeIdType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="protectionGroupType" type="ProtectionGroupTypes" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="revertive" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="operationalState" type="OperationalState"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="waitToRestoreTime" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Header">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="time" type="xsd:dateTime" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="uploaded" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="GlobalId" type="xsd:integer"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="AdaptationName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="AccessProtocol" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="ProprietaryMediatorAddress" type="NEAddressType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="ProprietaryElementAddress" type="NEAddressType"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="NE">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element ref="EQHO" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element ref="POSU" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element ref="FUUT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element ref="PRGR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOGeneralAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="MOStateAttributes"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="NEId" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="NEType" type="NETypes" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="systemTitle" type="SystemTitleType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="systemReleaseVersion" type="SystemReleaseVersionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="serialNumber" type="SerialNumberType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="softwareReleaseVersion" type="SoftwareReleaseVersionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="userLabel" type="UserLabelType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="vendorName" type="VendorNameType" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="version" type="VersionType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="locationName" type="LocationNameType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="HWCheckSum" type="HWCheckSumType"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="nameFromPlanningSystem" type="NameFromPlanningSystemType"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="HWData">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Header"/>
            <xsd:element ref="NE"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```